# Range of size of another tensor's dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to calculate a subset of a tensor in a following matter:
I have a tensor `T` and a tensor of indices `I`. I would like to get a tensor `C` such that:

```
C[i] = T[i, I[i]]
```

To do that I thought I'll do:

```
first_dim = I.get_shape()[0]
R = tf.range(first_dim)
S = tf.stack([R, I], 1)
tf.gather(T, S)
```

But I have a problem in the second line:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?
```

The shape of `I` is dependent on the size of some placeholder. Is there a different way to solve my problem or to get a range of size of another tensor's dimension, which is not know at TF-graph compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.shape` instead of `get_shape`.

Comment: Tried that, it still says this first dimension is undefined.